# What's wrong with my PHP curl request, please help .. I'm not getting any data back

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

It says the browser sent a request the server could not understand .. I don't exactly understand what went wrong in my PHP code. Can someone please help me understand where I went wrong. Thanks !

```
<?php
    $url ="http://127.0.0.1/sensor/sens/data.php";
    $xml_data = file_get_contents("/usr/local/www/data/data.xml");
    $header ="POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
    $header .="Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
    $header .="Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data)." \r\n";
    $header .="Content-transfer-encoding: text\r\n";
    $header .="Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $xml_data;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  // if the post is successful , the server will return some data.
    echo $data;

    #$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    #
    #if(!curl_errno($ch))
    #   echo 'It took '.$info['total_time'].'seconds to send a request to'.$info['url'];
    #
    #   else
    #

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;







    ?>
```

Comment: why are you putting $header into post fields and as customrequest ?

Comment: Please do not [duplicate your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978588/whats-wrong-with-my-php-curl-request-no-data-returned) only because you have got no answer so far. Instead edit the original question which is here to improve it. Better questions get better answers. Duplicating them will only drive potential friends away. The duplicate will get deleted sooner or later so you might want to take stuff from there to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

**From the PHP Manual...**

*The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.*

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

It should hold just the payload and not the entire header.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a custom request using cURL to make this request, a regular HTTP POST will suffice.  Another part of the problem is that you are also setting the `POSTFIELDS` and custom request to the same thing which was the HTTP request you constructed so the entire request consists largely of two duplicate strings.

Try this code and study it to understand how it works:

```
<?php

$url      = "http://127.0.0.1/sensor/sens/data.php";
$xml_data = file_get_contents("/usr/local/www/data/data.xml");

$headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml',
                 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: text',
                 'Connection: close');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);

$data = curl_exec($ch); // if the post is successful , the server will return
                        // some data.
echo $data;

// info = curl_getinfo($ch);
//
// f(!curl_errno($ch))
// echo 'It took '.$info['total_time'].'seconds to send a request
// to'.$info['url'];
//
// else
//

curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```